# Why does my Nodejs server not work on Windows?

Tags: node.js, express, http, server, port

I have started my Nodejs express server and opened port 3000 (the port the server is running on) in the Windows Firewall and restarted my Computer and the server still doesn't work on other devices in the local network. Why?

I've tried 10.0.0.16:3000/test and it doesn't work (local ip)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { parse } = require('querystring');

const PORT = 3000;


var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port " + PORT + "...");
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/test', (req,res) => {
  console.log("./test GET .. success");
  res.send("ok");
});



app.post('/projects', function(req,res) {

  console.log("./projects GET");

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  let body = req.body;

  let project_key = body.project_key;

  console.log(project_key);

  res.send("ok");

});
```

Comment: where are you getting `10.0.0.16` from?

Comment: that's my local ip the server is running on. (ipconfig: IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.16)

Comment: to access a device or this app over the network, you need to use the ip provided by the router, not a local one :/

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: My Windows Firewall is NOT controlled by the Control Panel since I have McAffe which does this! So I have to open the ports at McAffe!

Comment: You might want to install that, McAffee causes more security problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

I have McAffee and it's never blocked my node webserver.

Try this:

```
//Defines the server port (5000 for DEV)
```

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

```
//Initialises the server on ${PORT}
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`));
```